# Axios always catches

Tags: react-native, axios

I have a login code, which when a user logs in if the data is incorrect a backend made in nodejs returns a 401 error and if everything is correct returns a status code of 200.

During code execution, when the user is wrong in the data he executes the catch function correctly, but if he puts everything correct he does execute the "then" but also the catch.

Could someone help me with this problem?

```
async function handleLogin(){
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem('Authorization');
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem('ImAuthenticated');
        await api.post('/login', {
            email,
            password
        }, {
            headers: { 'device': 'mobile' }
        }).then(async(response)=>{
            const { hash } = response.data;
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("Authorization", hash);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("ImAuthenticated", true);
            navigation.navigate('Menu');
            console.log('oi');
        }).catch(function (error){
            if(error.response.data.showIn == "text"){
                setShowInfo(true);
                setEmail('');
                setPass('');
                this.InEmail.focus();
                if(error.response.data.level == 3){
                    setColorInfo(false);
                }else{
                    setColorInfo(true);
                }
                setInfoText(error.response.data.error);
            }else{
                setshowBox(true);
                setEmail('');
                setPass('');
                this.InEmail.focus();
                if(error.response.data.level == 3){
                    setcolorBox(false);
                }else{
                    setcolorBox(true);
                }
                setboxText(error.response.data.error);
        }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of the caught error?

Comment: [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'error.response.data')]
* src\pages\Login.js:27:34 in <unknown>
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne  
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in <unknown>  
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals

Comment: try to remove async before (response)=>